# Docker port mapping not working for a react mono-repo

Tags: reactjs, docker, monorepo

I am trying to run a mono repo application with following Docker

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.15

# Creating destination workspace folder to copy into
WORKDIR /app

# Copy all files from src to dest inside /app
COPY . .

# install dependancies
RUN yarn install 

RUN yarn global add nx

# build applications
RUN yarn run build

# Copy dist files
COPY ./dist/apps/project-web .

# Expose port
EXPOSE 4200

# required for docker desktop port mapping

#run app
CMD ["yarn", "run", "start"]
```

I ran following command to build the image:

```
docker build -f ./apps/project-web/Dockerfile . -t project-web1
```

My image was built successfully.

I spun up a docker container using following command

```
docker run --name project-web_c1 -p 3333:4200 -d project-web1
```

Locally, the app works fine on port 4200. But when I try to access it using port 3333 then it shows me below error:
[image]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "project-web",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nx serve",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test",
    "build-prod": "nx build --prod --app=project-web",
    "serve-prod": "yarn run build-prod && docker-compose up"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "3.6.5",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "0.13.7",
    "tslib": "2.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "6.3.0",
    "socket.io-client": "4.5.1",
    "@emotion/react": "11.9.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "11.8.1",
    "@mui/icons-material": "5.8.0",
    "@mui/lab": "5.0.0-alpha.83",
    "@mui/material": "5.8.1",
    "@mui/styles": "5.8.0",
    "axios": "0.27.2",
    "formik": "2.2.9",
    "moment": "2.29.3",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.34",
    "yup": "0.32.11",
    "react-text-mask": "5.4.3",
    "date-fns": "2.28.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nrwl/cli": "14.3.6",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "14.3.6",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "14.3.6",
    "@nrwl/jest": "14.3.6",
    "@nrwl/linter": "14.3.6",
    "@nrwl/nx-cloud": "latest",
    "@nrwl/react": "14.3.6",
    "@nrwl/web": "14.3.6",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "14.3.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "13.3.0", 
    "@types/node": "16.11.7",
    "@types/react": "18.0.13",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.5",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.24.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.24.0",
    "babel-jest": "27.5.1",
    "cypress": "9.1.0",
    "eslint": "8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "2.10.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.5.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.30.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "4.6.0",
    "jest": "27.5.1",
    "nx": "14.3.6",
    "prettier": "2.6.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "ts-jest": "27.1.4",
    "ts-node": "10.8.0",
    "typescript": "4.7.2",
    "@types/react-text-mask": "5.4.11",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.4",
    "@types/jest": "27.5.1"
  }
}
```

I am not using docker-compose yet. I am doing it simply using the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have multiple apps in your nx repo, you should be able to access react app by starting it alone with:

```
nx run project-web:serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disableHostCheck
```